# Customized Scala deserializer for all kinds of JValues

Tags: json, scala, serialization, deserialization, json4s

My problem: I have a Json structure I do not know the exact structure of. It could, for instance, be the following:

```
val json = JObject(List(
      ("text1", JString("testting <html>")),
      ("text2", JString("Test <script>script</script>")),
      ("text3", JObject(List(
        ("data", JObject(List(
          ("text", JString("Testing if <html> tags disappear </html>")),
          ("text2", JInt(2))
        )))
      ))
      )
    ))
```

I need to write a customized deserializer in Scala(using json4s) that iterates through the JValue(as, for instance, the one above) and removes ALL html tags from ALL JStrings within the JValue structure and then extraxts the final Jvalue structure to my Scala case classes. I have tried several solutions without any success.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ val regex = """<[^>]*>""".r
regex: util.matching.Regex = <[^>]*>
@ json transformField {
  case JField(k,JString(t)) => (k, JString(regex replaceAllIn(t,"")))
  }
res47: JValue = JObject(List((text1,JString(testting )), (text2,JString(Test script)), (text3,JObject(List((data,JObject(List((text,JString(Testing if  tags disappear )), (text2,JInt(2))))))))))
```

Simple actually, just use the transformField method provided by json4s and use an appropriate regex.